# SQL conditional statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a conditional statement in an ORACLE sql code 
I have a function in java that takes 2 parameters.
**getchildren(child1,child2)**..this function's parameters are used to create a query statement

```
public ResultSet getchildren(String Child1, String child2) throws SQLException 
{

 stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
 ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);


     query ="select * from table1 

            if child1 is not null and child2 is null
            { where child1 = 1 }
            else if child2 is not null AND child1 is null
            {where child2 = 2}
            else
             {//some other where statment } 
            ";



    System.out.println("\nExecuting query: " + query);
    rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    return rset;


}
```

This is obviously pseudocode.
I need help creating a conditional execution for the **where** clauses so that each **"where"** clause is executed when its condition is valid. I've tried something similar to what I have up there but with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a StringBuilder to dynamically build your query.

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
queryBuilder.append("select * from table1 ");

if ( child1 != null && child2 == null) 
   queryBuilder.append(" where child1 = 1 ");
else if ( child2 != null && child1 == null)
   queryBuilder.append(" where child2 = 1 ");
else
   queryBuilder.append(" where bla ");

// Execute queryBuilder.toString();
rset = stmt.executeQuery(queryBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Build up the query using a `StringBuilder` piece by piece.  Start by appending `"select * from table1 where "`.  Then write your `if` statements in plain Java, and in each block just append the appropriate clause.